# Firebase Facebook login check if user exist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I have an facebook login system which works with firebase but I want to check if user exist on my firebase (i don't want to add it, just want to make sure if he exist because I want to redirect user to another page to complete its profile, once its done I'll want to send it to firebase).

I just need to check if user exist on my db. Here is the code that I try but it returns nil error and it automatically add user to firebase.

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)


FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
        // ... 

}
```

Comment: check with reauthenticate method ...

Comment: can you give me a link or sth about that method? because i couldnt find it on firebase website.

Comment: ya sure ... check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) ..  at the end of this page you found reAuthenticate method

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reauthenticateWithCredential` method to check user is exist or not.

Check [this Doc.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users) , section -> Re-authenticate a user

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
var credential: FIRAuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
    // An error happened.
  } else {
    // User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

If user re-authenticated successfully that means user is existed...

Comment: The main issue is when user have an account but he delete the app then reinstall it , this code will not work, because . currentUser is nil. Better way is to check the .reference().child("users/currentUserId")(or where you store data for logged in user) if object exists

Comment: @ConstantinSaulenco then we need to move the code that checks the user to the server side, as we don't want user data to be visible to anyone