# Issue converting old firebase code to latest version

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, ios9, firebase-realtime-database

Good Evening,

I'm currently studying `iOS` development along with `Firebase`.

I'm having a small issues converting some `Firebase` code to the latest version of `Firebase`, Inside my lecture, the tutor has set his project up like so:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class DataService {

   static let ds = DataService()

   private var _REF_BASE = Firebase (url: "MyURL")

   var REF_BASE: Firebase {
       return _REF_BASE
   }

}
```

Then inside the `ViewController` he has the following:

```
DataService.ds.REF_BASE.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", Token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in 


})
```

I'm currently using the latest version of `Firebase` my code is some what different as shown here:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

class DataService {

static let ds = DataService()

private var _REF_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

var ref: FIRDatabase {

    return _REF_BASE

}
}
```

First issue I have is on `return _REF_BASE` it says:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'FIRDatabaseReference' to return type FIRDatabase

Next inside my `ViewController` I have the following:

```
DataService.ds.ref.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", Token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in


 })
```

However the error I've receiving is:

> value of type `FIRDatabase` has no member `authWithOAuthProvider`

I have asked the teacher is he has updated code for this lecture however it's been a few days and I can only assume he does not.

Now I'm completely new to `Firebase` and getting it integrated within `IOS` so if someone could share their knowledge on how I go about converting the code provided in the lecture to the latest version of Firebase I'd highly appreciate it.

**Update**

I've been browsing the web trying to find a solution for this, I have tried searching for information on the given answer provided below however I'm unable to find any ideal solution, can anyone suggest any other ideas on how I go about converting the old firebase to the new one?

Comment: I don't really know about their OAuth stuff as I have not read into their framework, but the first error is because you are trying to return a database reference to a var expecting a database object.  The line private var _REF_BASE = FIRDatabase.database().reference() assigns it to the FIRDataBaseReference type - the object you want is the database that var references -- is there a method that returns a database object from a db reference? If so you will need to use that

Comment: @Neuronical apologies on the late reply, been searching the web trying to find a solution however I've been unsuccessful. I've also searched for you have mentioned again been unsuccessful.

Comment: `var ref: FIRDatabaseReference { return _REF_BASE }`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Thanks, that got rid of the error in the DataService file, but I'm still unable to fix the errors in the View Controller i.e passing the access token return from facebook to Firebase. Any suggestions?

Comment: @CodeRatchet is this for fblogin????

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0  Correct, I'm currently using the Facebook SDK so I make a call to Facebook and return the Access Token, I then need to pass the access token to Firebase to confirm whether or not this person exists in the db

Comment: check this .. method is completely different now https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/tFIi5ugrdGo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is of type .. `FIRDatabase` should be `FIRDatabaseReference`

```
  var ref: FIRDatabaseReference { return _REF_BASE }
```

For FB authentication, method is changed completely ... [Full guide here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/facebook-login#authenticate_with_firebase)

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
    // ...
}
```

And to check user exists in database or not [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435080/firebase-facebook-login-check-if-user-exist/38435639#38435639)

Comment: Thanks, I think when I continue with this online course, as it seems to be outdated I'll follow what they're trying achieve then I'll convert to Firebase2.

Comment: yes .. there is new doc which I provide you with new APIS and methods