# No output when calling user?.reauthenticate with Facebook token

Tags: ios, authentication, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I trying to check if the authenticated user already exist in Firebase. I found that `user?.reauthenticate` can solve this, but unfortunately, when I run it, it gets stuck on `reauthenticate` method. I do not see any error messages in console. I run the code on an iOS simulator.

Can somebody help me with this? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks

```
    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {


    self.loginButton.isHidden = true
        self.loadspinnerAIV.startAnimating()

    if(error != nil){
        //handle errors
        self.loginButton.isHidden = false
        self.loadspinnerAIV.stopAnimating()
    }else if(result.isCancelled){
        //handle cancel event
        self.loginButton.isHidden = false
        self.loadspinnerAIV.stopAnimating()
    }else{
        let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

        let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
        user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print ("User does not exist")
                FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in}
            } else {
                print ("User does exist")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showHome", sender: self)

            }
        }
    }
}.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Facebook login check if user exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435080/firebase-facebook-login-check-if-user-exist)

Comment: Maybe it the same question but it does not work for me. So that why I made a new post.